# Facebook thumbnail image

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, client, thumbnails

How do I select an image to show as a thumnail for when someone likes something on a site. Right now I have this

```
<fb:like layout="button_count" colorscheme="light" href="myurl" ref="something" show_faces="false" width="150"></fb:like>
```

When something is liked it seems like a random image is sent to the facebook wall, I'd like to send a specific image. to facebook based on what page my content was liked

Answer (score 3):

I think it's the Facebook Open Graph tags you are looking for, specifically the `og:image` tag.

Try viewing these links:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ specifically the "open graph tags" section.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: You can check which data is fetched by facebook (and update it, if the data has changed) here : http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: this looks good, but I am not really able to access this image in the file that controls my header (where the og:image tag needs to go) (also javascript does not seem to effect it)